# php - error on function with case + if

Tags: php, database, function, pdo

Hello I have function like this it looks like I cannot call function inside switch. any idea ?

```
function isEmailExists($email) {
   $result = query('SELECT email FROM parents WHERE email = :email', array('email' => $email));
   return ($result) ? 1 : 0;
}

function usernameEmailCheck($field, $value) {
    $message = '';
    switch ($field) {
        case 'email':
            if($result = isEmailExists($value)) {
                $message = "Email already exists!";
            }
            break;
    }
    return $message;
}
```

Comment: besides the typo for what should have been a comparison `==`, this is most likely an out of scope issue.

Comment: Make `array('email' =>`??

Comment: @KarloKokkak thats parameters, i create a query function so i dont need to type prepare and execute everytime I want to query. I just need to put sql query syntax and parameters inside an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doing assignment not comparison

```
if($result = isUsernameExists($value)) {
```

Assignment is one `=`, Comparison is `==` or `===`

I imagine your if condition always passes, well if this function returns a true type value.

I thought maybe it was intentional?  It's valid to do it that way, but I don't see you using `$result` for anything.  It's also a common mistake to make because there is no error issued for it.

### update

> Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Has nothing to do with the case statement.  This error has to do with not assign the correct number of bound variablse to a prepared statement.  For example

```
 $stmt = $PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM foo WHERE a = :a AND b = :b');
 $stmt->execute([':a'=>$a]);
```

See I have `a` and `b` and give it only one. That would cause the same error.  It's an error I know very well, me and that one are friends.

Here is a PRO-tip: it's generally a good idea to mention any specific errors that are issued by PHP, tends to help one diagnose the issue.

Comment: what i got is an error Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number

Comment: What? that has nothing to do with what you said in the question.

Comment: tried to changed to comparison as well, but i still get the same error, dunno why

Comment: That error has nothing to do with this function.  That is a database error for not assigning the correct number of variable to a prepared statement.  I would guess it's located in this function `isUsernameExists`

Comment: just figured out i have union query thats need 2 parameters, I put 1 parameter

Answer (score -1):

```
function isEmailExists($email) {
    $result = query('SELECT email FROM parents WHERE email = :email', array('email' => $email));
    return (count($result)>0) ? true : false;
}

if(isEmailExists($value)) {
    $message = "Email already exists!";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.